# Something wrong with connectionstring

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, authentication, connection-string

I am writing a login page in visual studio.net 2010 . (c#)
I have made a class which some methods are in it . this includes :

```
namespace SchoolsNetwork
{
public class cUsers2
{
    SqlConnection SchoolsDBConnectionString;
    SqlDataAdapter sda;
            SqlCommandBuilder scb;
 SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
 "SchoolsDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);


public DsUsers2  Checkpassword(string UserName, string password,out bool Success)
    {
        DsUsers2 dsUsers=new DsUsers2();
        string SqlStr="select * from tblMembers  where Username='"+UserName+"' and Password='"+password+"'";
        sda.SelectCommand=new SqlCommand(SqlStr,SchoolsDBConnectionString);

        sda.Fill(dsUsers.tblMembers);
        Success=dsUsers.tblMembers.Rows.Count>0;
        return dsUsers ;
    }
```

Then in my form.aspx page I have textfield for entering username and password and a button for clicking to login. the code for the button is :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtuser.Text.Trim().Length>0 && txtpass.Value.Length>0 )
        {  
            cUsers2 cUsers=new cUsers2();
            DsUsers2 dsUser=new DsUsers2();
            bool Success;
            if (txtuser.Text.Trim()=="admin")
            {
                Success=cUsers.CheckAdminPass(txtuser.Text.Trim(),txtpass.Value.Trim());  
                if (Success)
                {
                    Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx");
                }
            }

            dsUser=cUsers.Checkpassword(txtuser.Text.Trim(), txtpass.Value.Trim(),out Success);
            if(Success)
            {
                Session["ID"]=dsUser.tblMembers.Rows[0][dsUser.tblMembers.IDUserColumn].ToString();
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("frmProfile.aspx");

            }
            else lblerror.Text="invalid username & password";

        }
    }
```

in web.config I have this as connectionstring :

```
<configuration>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data     source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="SchoolsDBConnectionString" connectionString="
Data Source=Sunny-LPTP\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=SchoolsDB;Integrated Security=True"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

after debugging, this line is noted as error :

```
sda.SelectCommand=new SqlCommand(SqlStr,SchoolsDBConnectionString);
```

it says

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: p.s. as a side note your Checkpassword is vulnerable to a sql injection attack.

Comment: could you please format your code well? It seems that the line 8 will not be compiled.

Comment: Considering the pasted code wouldn't even compile, it's hard to know if it's accurate or not. As it stands, you haven't initiated `sda` to an actual `SqlDataAdapter`.

Comment: Nor have you initiated SchoolsDBConnectionString. And I would rename that, it's the connection, not a connectionstring.

Comment: Magrangs & allentranks :which line do u mean ? whats wrong with it?

Comment: The obligatory Little Bobby Tables: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: JSteen & NetWave : can u please write it for me that what should I add to the code ? thank u

Comment: @SunnY In checkPassword you are not sanitizing your inputs for username and password. Take a look at this section 2.1 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 1):

You need to **create an instance for sda**.

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SELECT_STMT, CONNECTION)

// according to your project
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(SqlStr,SchoolsDBConnectionString);
```

See [**MSDN SqlDataAdapter constructor**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.sqldataadapter%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Furhtermore you should really care about **SQL Injection**. Make use of [SqlParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.aspx).

*Some things you should consider*

- using block
- SqlParameter instead of string concatenation
- use ExecuteScalar to access only one value / DataAdapter.Fill to acquire a table

A rough example on your code could be:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CONNECTION_STRING))
{
    string selStmt = "select count(*) from ABC where username=@username and passwort=@password";
    SqlCommand cmd= new SqlCommand (selStmt, con);

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", SqlDbType.Varchar);
    cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = USERNAME_FROM_TEXTBOX

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.Varchar);
    cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = PASSWORD_FROM_TEXTBOX

    return int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()) > 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're getting this exception because you have not initialized the "sda" object:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda;
```

You need to initialize it:

```
sda = new SqlDataAdapter(...);
```

Comment: I did but still doesnt work. error with  :   sda.Fill(dsUsers.tblMembers);  while debugging. its null

Comment: Thank you I just changed web.config and initializing sda, then it didnt the previous Error. but now it says :  Login failed for user ''. when I try to set the user as "Sunny" it says Login failed for user 'Sunny'. so whats wrong ? I use SQLExpress2008 and there is no sql athuntication on it. I start sql with windows authentication and the username there is : sunny-lptp\sunny

Answer (score 0):

you should create a object instance before you use it

```
// call constructor before you use code 
 sda = new SqlDataAdapter();       
 sda.SelectCommand=new SqlCommand(SqlStr,SchoolsDBConnectionString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a `SchoolsDBConnectionString` object, it's just defined not initialized.

You may try following:

```
SqlConnection SchoolsDBConnectionString = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["SchoolsDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
```

Late you have just defined the field `SqlDataAdapter sda` not initialized it.
So write following:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(YourQueryVariable, SchoolsDBConnectionString);
```

Comment: Thank you I just changed web.config and initializing sda, then it didnt the previous Error. but now it says : Login failed for user ''. when I try to set the user as "Sunny" it says Login failed for user 'Sunny'. so whats wrong ? I use SQLExpress2008 and there is no sql athuntication on it. I start sql with windows authentication and the username there is : sunny-lptp\sunny